# PHP Form textarea placeholder not working

Tags: php, forms, deployment

I am not sure if it is possible, but I have a contact form.
I want after a submit, that the textarea is still present.

My code that I have is:

```
<textarea class="field" type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="8" required placeholder="Your message here! (Required)">
       <?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
        echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?>
 </textarea>
```

This works but it is lacking. The placeholder text is gone, because the if(isset()..) The method leaves me blank spaces, and I want to have a placeholder text.

My other question is: I am experienced in programming, but not really with webdevelopment, Is it okay to use in the year 2023 a php formular or is this method outdated?

Comment: Ok, i got the issue. The misterious blank spaces, came from my formatting. The code is working flawless. But still, is a PHP outdated?